# Eclipse CDT Autocomplete not working

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I remember from some time ago that Eclipse had auto-complete when you type, and now I can only get it when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>. I already checked and don't have any unresolved dependencies,  I can see all the auto-complete choices when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, but that's not something I like to do every-time... Can someone point me in the direction to get auto-complete back? (Using CDT C++)

Comment: I have a similar problem where I don't get autocomplete when pressing CTRL+Space (Eclipse Juno CDT on OSX)

Comment: I'm have a similar problem, I tried many "solutions" like adding every path in C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols, but the problem is still here. Did you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

At some point recently (not sure but since March 2013?) my Eclipse `CDT` stopped auto completion. I figured out that at `Editor`->`Content Assist`->`Advanced` checking `Parsing-based Proposals` lets auto completion work on my machine.

Ubuntu 12.10, Eclipse 4.2.2, CDT 8.1.2

[image]

This snapshot shows `Task-Focused`, which I don't see on my another `Eclipse` instance. In that case I just checked `Parsing-based Proposals` and completion still works.

Comment: In kepler this menu is under Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Editor etc

Comment: How do i get to that specific menu in Eclipse. Ive been looking for like the last 5 or 10 minutes and every menu i open is labelled properties.

Comment: I still need to press `Ctrl+Space`  to get auto completion window . is there any way to achieve auto completion  without pressing these keys ?

Comment: Does not work for me. I do get some proposals, but nothing from the standard libraries. std::string s g gives not autocomplete..

Comment: My problem is more complicated it doesn't work for me at all even when I press ctrl + space it doesn't show me anything

Answer (score 14):

This question is so valid even in 2018 with eclipse photon.

1) Go to Window > Prefrences > C/C++ > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced.

2) Check "Parsing-based proposal(Task-focused)".

3) Bind a key now by pressing "Ctrl + Space".

[image]

Comment: This works, but in general something strange happened with keyboard in Photon: not only ctrl+space is not working in CDT, but also ctrl+right(left)arrow etc although I can see its binding in Eclipse menu.

Comment: What operating system are you using? It works good for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried Photon on both Ubuntu 16.04 and W10 on completely different PC -- neither are stable. Also it is heisenbug: sometimes it exist, sometimes all works good with no change in the settings, also I see no correlation with system restart.

Comment: I have Eclipse CDT version 2019-06 (4.12.0) on KDE Plasma 5.16.4
Is there a way to "auto-invoke" the content assistant (Visual Studio style, without any shortcut(s)) ?

Comment: @Roey, I do not think eclipse CDT supports visual studio style auto-completion yet. But if you need it for java, it is straight forward to achieve that. You can refer to this video of mine on youtube; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q83wCCxpqnI

Comment: @AmitKr great idea & nice vid. Yeah it's pitty Eclipse CDT doesn't support full auto-invoke I don't get this "semi-automatic" (manual invoke) mechanism . I use VS Code instead. TNX

Comment: This is still a problem in version 2020-03. In addition when registering the key binding "when" must be changed to "In Windows". This was set to the task editor only in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with Eclipse Juno (OSX Java "1.6.0_33") where the autocomplete (and save key binding) wasn't working properly.  Googling I found this: [Eclipse JUNO doesn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310970/eclipse-juno-doesnt-start)

Updating my Mercurial Plugin to the latest (1.9.1) fixed both these issues for me.

Very weird.