# Eclipse CDT Intellisense Not Updating C++

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-kepler, content-assist

I am working on a C++ project using `Eclipse Kepler V4.3.1` with the `CDT` plugins on Fedora. Up until yesterday, everything seemed to be working fine, but now when I make a change `Intellisense`/`Content Assist` doesn't seem to see it. (*Note that this is not the same problem with getting autocomplete to make suggestions that I have seen [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399719/eclipse-cdt-autocomplete-not-working) post about.*)

For example, if Eclipse picks up on an error like passing an invalid argument to a function, when I then go and fix the error Eclipse continues to complain about it. It continues to show me the old line before I made the change. If I open that same file with Emacs or gedit, I see that in fact the change was made and saved.

Here is what I have tried without success:

- Right click on the project  > Index > Rebuild
- Right click on the project  > Index > Freshen All Files
- Right click on the project  > Index > Update with Modifies Files
- Restarting Eclipse
- Restarting the entire machine
- Checking for software updates and installing them (plus restarting).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others who might run into this issue, I wish I had a better solution but here is what solved it:

- Delete the entire build directory
- Clean the project
- Delete the files I had been working on and re-add them.
- Right click on the project > Index > Rebuild
- Restart Eclipse

I'm not sure which part actually did it since I had also previously installed updates, but things seem to be working again.