# Omnet++ Aotu-Completion doesn't work

Tags: autocomplete, linker, omnet++

Im building a project in Omnet++ and when Im trying to use

```
 Ctrl + Space
```

In any of the modules , I dont get auto completion to anything from the .h file's I have include.

I dont get any error or warning on any of the #include's I do , 
and no problem in compiling the project.

What to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The OMNeT++ IDE is relying on the Eclipse CDT for editing C++ code. There seems to be a question (with answer) that deals with autocomplete problems of Eclipse CDT on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16139076/4707703). It might apply to your problem as well.