# Code-completion doesn't work in Eclipse CDT Oxygen

Tags: eclipse-cdt, code-completion

I expect code-completion must provide me suggestions for class names and (previously declared) variable names by pressing Ctrl+Space. But it doesn't (see sample below). What I do wrong?
PS: This issue is different from [those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399719/eclipse-cdt-autocomplete-not-working) one.

[image: Code sample]

Comment: It's possible you have a problem with your project configuration, or that you're running into a bug in Eclipse CDT. I can't tell what's wrong by looking at a partial code screenshot. Please [file a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) with a complete code example.

Comment: I reported [a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=525973) as it occurs on brand new project after restart of IDE.