# Eclipse Juno Startup error log file

Tags: eclipse

I've been using Eclipse Juno perfectly fine until recently when I started it up I received the following error:

An error has occurred. See the log file
C:\Users\Quinn\workspace.metadata.log

I've relatively new to programming so any help in layman's terms would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

The .log file was incredibly long so I'm only adding the last part. If you need more info. please don't be afraid to ask. Thanks!

```
!SESSION 2012-08-04 12:08:30.616 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.6.0_33
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2012-08-04 12:08:32.307
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 4 2 2012-08-04 12:08:34.434
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.equinox.preferences".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.preferences.PreferenceInitializer.initializeDefaultPreferences(PreferenceInitializer.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper$1.run(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.runInitializer(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferencesService.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.applyRuntimeDefaults(DefaultPreferences.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.load(DefaultPreferences.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.AbstractScope.getNode(AbstractScope.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.DefaultScope.getNode(DefaultScope.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.getDefaultPreferences(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.getPreferenceNodes(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.internalGet(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.getBoolean(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.describer.JavaSourceUiDescriber.isGUISource(JavaSourceUiDescriber.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.describer.JavaSourceUiDescriber.describe(JavaSourceUiDescriber.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.describe(ContentTypeCatalog.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.collectMatchingByContents(ContentTypeCatalog.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.internalFindContentTypesFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.internalFindContentTypesFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.getDescriptionFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.getDescriptionFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeMatcher.getDescriptionFor(ContentTypeMatcher.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ContentDescriptionManager.readDescription(ContentDescriptionManager.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ContentDescriptionManager.getDescriptionFor(ContentDescriptionManager.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.internalGetCharset(File.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getCharset(File.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getCharset(File.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.Util.getResourceContentsAsCharArray(Util.java:1156)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.SourceFile.getContents(SourceFile.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ReadManager.run(ReadManager.java:173)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDevice(Display.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getSystemFont(Display.java:2459)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceConverter.<clinit>(PreferenceConverter.java:84)
    ... 35 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-08-04 12:08:35.102
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceConverter
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.themes.ThemeElementHelper.installFont(ThemeElementHelper.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.themes.ThemeElementHelper.populateRegistry(ThemeElementHelper.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$27.runWithException(Workbench.java:1550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2478)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$7(Workbench.java:2386)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2012-08-04 12:08:36.083
!MESSAGE parseSdkContent failed
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin.getDisplay(AdtPlugin.java:334)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin$7.run(AdtPlugin.java:1422)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
!SESSION 2012-08-04 12:25:48.967 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.6.0_33
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2012-08-04 12:25:50.607
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 4 2 2012-08-04 12:25:52.846
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.equinox.preferences".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.preferences.PreferenceInitializer.initializeDefaultPreferences(PreferenceInitializer.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper$1.run(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:300)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.runInitializer(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:131)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferencesService.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.applyRuntimeDefaults(DefaultPreferences.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.load(DefaultPreferences.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:663)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.node(EclipsePreferences.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.AbstractScope.getNode(AbstractScope.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.preferences.DefaultScope.getNode(DefaultScope.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.getDefaultPreferences(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.getPreferenceNodes(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.internalGet(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:475)
    at org.eclipse.ui.preferences.ScopedPreferenceStore.getBoolean(ScopedPreferenceStore.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.describer.JavaSourceUiDescriber.isGUISource(JavaSourceUiDescriber.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.describer.JavaSourceUiDescriber.describe(JavaSourceUiDescriber.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.describe(ContentTypeCatalog.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.collectMatchingByContents(ContentTypeCatalog.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.internalFindContentTypesFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.internalFindContentTypesFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.getDescriptionFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeCatalog.getDescriptionFor(ContentTypeCatalog.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentTypeMatcher.getDescriptionFor(ContentTypeMatcher.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ContentDescriptionManager.readDescription(ContentDescriptionManager.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ContentDescriptionManager.getDescriptionFor(ContentDescriptionManager.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.internalGetCharset(File.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getCharset(File.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.File.getCharset(File.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.util.Util.getResourceContentsAsCharArray(Util.java:1156)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.SourceFile.getContents(SourceFile.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ReadManager.run(ReadManager.java:173)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4247)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.checkDevice(Display.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getSystemFont(Display.java:2459)
    at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceConverter.<clinit>(PreferenceConverter.java:84)
    ... 35 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2012-08-04 12:25:53.650
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceConverter
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.themes.ThemeElementHelper.installFont(ThemeElementHelper.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.themes.ThemeElementHelper.populateRegistry(ThemeElementHelper.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$27.runWithException(Workbench.java:1550)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2478)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$7(Workbench.java:2386)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)

!ENTRY com.android.ide.eclipse.adt 4 0 2012-08-04 12:25:54.453
!MESSAGE parseSdkContent failed
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin.getDisplay(AdtPlugin.java:334)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin$7.run(AdtPlugin.java:1422)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: what is in the log file?

Comment: Show `C:\Users\Quinn\workspace.metadata.log`

Comment: This isn't just a Juno error - I got the same error with Kepler. Gabriel's accepted answer below solved it.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

I am having the same problem with Eclipse Juno, which I use for Android development.

As a workaround for Windows, I launch it from the console like this:

```
C:\path\to\eclipse\eclipse -clean
```

As hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310970/eclipse-juno-doesnt-start), you can also try to delete the file YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap

This also worked for me and (so far) seemed to fix the problem permanently, unlike the first option.

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately it is still not working at all.

Comment: Removing the .snap file solved the issue for me as well. Thank you Gabriel.

Comment: I wasn not able to fix this using the above given solution. I had to reinstall eclipse and import all my plugins

Comment: There is no .snap ! And clean not working. so what can i do now?!

Comment: Hi, Mr. Hyde. If you're using Eclipse Kepler, it appears that there is indeed no .snap file anymore. Since I cannot reproduce your problem (it all works well for me), could you tell me what error you are getting exactly? If you try @jayeffkay's answer below, does it fix your problem?

Comment: @HarmeetSingh good to know. Kind of sad to hear that this problem persists into Eclipse Luna though

Answer (score 32):

I got my workspace starting again by deleting

> org.eclipse.e4.workbench

from the .plugins folder. Then starting with the `-clean` flag.

Comment: This removed all my projects in the workspace. You could as well just delete the .metadata folder...

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me, but not the previous tips I've seen here! I just lost one class, don't really understand why... But it's an easy one to "recode"

Answer (score 5):

In Mac you need to delete this file of your workspace

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap
```

Answer (score 4):

**Delete**: `/[PATH TO WORKSPACE]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources`
It will get eclipse back to work

Comment: it didn't work for me. Eclipse did start but without any project libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Cut the plugin folder out org.eclipse.core.resources [may be to the desktop] and start the eclipse. Now, you will see the eclipse open with out the projects. Now close the eclipse and Copy the plugin folder back again and start the eclipse. Now you should see all your projects with eclipse working open.

Comment: Tried the other solutions but eclipse still did not start. Tried this solution and success! Thanks @NareshVankuru

Answer (score 2):

Go to your eclipse workspace and locate the .snap file in the given path

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap
```

deleting the snap file should do the magic, what are .snap files well  AFAIK

.snap files contains all the changes in workspace state of the IDE during the runtime and are used for eclipse crash recovery plan.

Answer (score 1):

I have deleted metadata folder and restart eclipse and imported all project from same workspace folder. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error on Windows 8. Running eclipse as Administrator solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the org.eclipse.core.resources folder at Workspace.metadata.plugins. But you will have to import all projects to the eclipse again hence we delete the resource handling folder of eclipse. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Simple delete .metadata file in your worksapce and again create a workspace using the same path. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Delete: /YOUR PATH TO WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources

This worked for me