# Eclipse Juno Not Loading - stuck on 'org.eclipse.m2e,core'

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I was working fine with an Eclipse Juno on a Maven java project - all hunky-dory for couple of weeks.

Yesterday, just before leaving for home, I ran 'mvn clean' and 'mvn install' on the command line for the project (all good). I did not try opening Eclipse after running 'mvn' on said project from the command line.

This morning opening Eclipse Juno does not work - it stalls on loading 'org.eclipse.m2e,core'.

Can anyone give guidance on what could be going on?

I would rather not delete Eclipse and re-install - too painful!!!

I am using Macbook with Oracle JVM 7.

Answer (score 8):

Delete the folder ".org.eclipse.e4.workbench" in ".metadata/.plugins" within the problem workspace and start eclipse with the -clean flag.
If this doesn't help also delete all files ".markers.snap".

Comment: I deleted only ".org.eclipse.e4.workbench" and it works.

Comment: Deleted only "org.eclipse.e4.workbench" too and it works, but some workspace configurations are lost after you do it.

Answer (score 3):

I just have to delete the file **workbench.xmi** from directory

```
[*workspaceXYZ*]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench
```

Then the workspace starts again. But this is really a pain...

Answer (score 2):

Just adding extra case for same old problem (as i encountered the problem now and was able to solve it):
For me too i had exactly same problem, other work space were working except for this. I did not wanted to delete this problematic workspace. So what I did was, first I loaded some other work space for which eclipse starts. Then I clicked "switch work space" and tried to open the same work space which had was problem. Then it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can try steps in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810102/eclipse-juno-startup-error-log-file). This didn't work for me so then I tried deleting the whole *workspace*/.meta folder. This did work for me but I now have to reimport my projects - so not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your eclipse in doing something with M2E the maven plugin, maybe try to remove the plugin from eclipse installation first. Then try to restart eclipse.
If everything is ok, then install the plugin agian.

Answer (score 0):

To me was necessary to do both solutions above:

1. Delete the folder ".org.eclipse.e4.workbench" in ".metadata/.plugins"
2. I loaded some other work space for which eclipse starts. Then I clicked "switch work space" and tried to open the same work space which had was problem.

Then it worked!!! :D