# Eclipse Neon "Customize perspective" provokes a "StackOverflowError"

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, stack-overflow

Eclipse "Customize perspective" provokes a "StackOverflowError" (see partial stacktrace below), the screen will never show and Eclipse can become unstable and may not start again.

This happens on Spring Tool Suite (sts-3.8.3) based on Eclipse 4.6.2 running on Ubuntu 16.x (and probably on other Linux too).

How to unlock Eclipse and how to make "Custom perspective" work with this version ?

stacktrace :

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.eclipse.swt.events.ControlEvent.<init>(ControlEvent.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:225)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:5227)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1340)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1366)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1345)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setBounds(Control.java:1100)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setBounds(Composite.java:1527)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolBar.setBounds(ToolBar.java:589)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setLocation(Control.java:1187)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.setFramedControlLocation(ImageBasedFrame.java:124)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame.access$0(ImageBasedFrame.java:120)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.widgets.ImageBasedFrame$4.controlMoved(ImageBasedFrame.java:109)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:225)
(...)
```

Comment: Can you try to edit eclipse.ini to increase you stack size with `-Xss1m` ?

Comment: It's not a memory setting problem, it's an infinite event loop. It's a known eclipse bug : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=497705

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If Eclipse is locked, it's not useful to remove the "writer.lock" file visible in logs, you have to remove the "workbench.xmi" located in your workspace :

```
<workspace_path>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
```

(tip taken here : [Eclipse (C/C++) Error: Job found still running after platform shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13328278/eclipse-c-c-error-job-found-still-running-after-platform-shutdown))

To enable the "Customize perspective" screen, you have to switch to GTK 2. To do so, just edit your eclipse.ini (or STS.ini) and replace this :

```
--launcher.defaultAction
```

by this :

```
--launcher.GTK_version
2
```