# Eclipse will not start and I haven't changed anything

Tags: java, eclipse

I haven't updated anything for at least a month.  I was just working normally and suddenly the menus were all blank, so I decided to restart eclipse. I clicked "close" and "ok" to save everything, but nothing happened, so I clicked close again and eclipse closed. I clicked on eclipse and the loading screen only flashes and disappears followed by a message telling me to check the `.log` file. I've since restarted the pc multiple times, tried running it in safe mode and ran `eclipse.exe -clean` and nothing works.

Any ideas?

```
!SESSION 2013-03-12 13:46:10.078 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.7.0_07
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product -clean

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-03-12 13:46:55.800
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1228)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2013-03-12 13:46:55.803
!MESSAGE An unexpected exception was thrown.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1228)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-03-12 13:46:55.811
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1228)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-03-12 13:47:01.331
!MESSAGE While loading class "org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.SVNTeamUIPlugin", thread "Thread[main,6,main]" timed out waiting (5003ms) for thread "Thread[Worker-1,5,main]" to finish starting bundle "org.eclipse.team.svn.ui_1.0.0.I20120803-1700 [691]". To avoid deadlock, thread "Thread[main,6,main]" is proceeding but "org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.SVNTeamUIPlugin" may not be fully initialized.
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: State change in progress for bundle "reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.team.svn.ui_1.0.0.I20120803-1700.jar" by thread "Worker-1".
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1088)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    ... 38 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle$BundleStatusException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.beginStateChange(AbstractBundle.java:1088)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-03-12 13:47:02.259
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    ... 18 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2013-03-12 13:47:02.519
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven.internal.legacyconversion.LegacyProjectChecker.earlyStartup(LegacyProjectChecker.java:36)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-03-12 13:47:02.521
!MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

!ENTRY org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven 4 0 2013-03-12 13:47:02.523
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.maven.internal.legacyconversion.LegacyProjectChecker.earlyStartup(LegacyProjectChecker.java:36)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2013-03-12 13:47:02.529
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.osgi.targetdefinition.TargetStartup.earlyStartup(TargetStartup.java:58)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-03-12 13:47:02.531
!MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

!ENTRY org.springframework.ide.eclipse.osgi.targetdefinition 4 0 2013-03-12 13:47:02.534
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.osgi.targetdefinition.TargetStartup.earlyStartup(TargetStartup.java:58)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2013-03-12 13:47:02.550
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui.internal.legacyconversion.LegacySTSChecker".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui.internal.legacyconversion.LegacySTSChecker.<clinit>(LegacySTSChecker.java:44)
    ... 18 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2013-03-12 13:47:02.551
!MESSAGE Plug-in "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui.internal.legacyconversion.LegacySTSChecker".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui.internal.legacyconversion.LegacySTSChecker.<clinit>(LegacySTSChecker.java:44)
    ... 18 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2013-03-12 13:47:02.551
!MESSAGE Plug-in "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui.internal.legacyconversion.LegacySTSChecker".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui.internal.legacyconversion.LegacySTSChecker.<clinit>(LegacySTSChecker.java:44)
    ... 18 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.ui 4 0 2013-03-12 13:47:02.552
!MESSAGE Monitor UI stop failed
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.monitor.ui.ActivityContextManager.stop(ActivityContextManager.java:150)
    ...
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-03-12 13:47:02.553
!MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

!ENTRY org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui 4 0 2013-03-12 13:47:02.555
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui.internal.legacyconversion.LegacySTSChecker".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui.internal.legacyconversion.LegacySTSChecker.<clinit>(LegacySTSChecker.java:44)
    ... 18 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.registry 4 1 2013-03-12 13:47:02.555
!MESSAGE Plug-in "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui" was unable to instantiate class "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui.internal.legacyconversion.LegacySTSChecker".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.getExecutableExtension(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui.internal.legacyconversion.LegacySTSChecker.<clinit>(LegacySTSChecker.java:44)
    ... 18 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2013-03-12 13:47:02.562
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.internal.configurator.ConfiguratorImporter.lazyStartup(ConfiguratorImporter.java:369)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.internal.ui.StartupExtensionPointReader.runStartupExtension(StartupExtensionPointReader.java:64)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.internal.ui.StartupExtensionPointReader.runStartupExtensions(StartupExtensionPointReader.java:47)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.internal.ui.StartupExtensionPointReader.earlyStartup(StartupExtensionPointReader.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-03-12 13:47:02.563
!MESSAGE Unhandled Exception

!ENTRY org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.ui 4 0 2013-03-12 13:47:02.565
!MESSAGE Unable to execute early startup code for an extension
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.internal.configurator.ConfiguratorImporter.lazyStartup(ConfiguratorImporter.java:369)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.internal.ui.StartupExtensionPointReader.runStartupExtension(StartupExtensionPointReader.java:64)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.internal.ui.StartupExtensionPointReader.runStartupExtensions(StartupExtensionPointReader.java:47)
    at org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.internal.ui.StartupExtensionPointReader.earlyStartup(StartupExtensionPointReader.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$52.run(Workbench.java:2357)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-03-12 13:47:02.671
!MESSAGE An unexpected runtime error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.BlockedJobsDialog.createBlockedDialog(BlockedJobsDialog.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchDialogBlockedHandler.showBlocked(WorkbenchDialogBlockedHandler.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchDialogBlockedHandler.showBlocked(WorkbenchDialogBlockedHandler.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.EventLoopProgressMonitor.setBlocked(EventLoopProgressMonitor.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.reportBlocked(JobManager.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.join(JobManager.java:907)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.stop(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:870)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.core.ProvisioningAgent.unregisterService(ProvisioningAgent.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.core.ProvisioningAgent.removedService(ProvisioningAgent.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerRemoved(ServiceTracker.java:956)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerRemoved(ServiceTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.untrack(AbstractTracked.java:341)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.unregister(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.disposeInstances(InstanceProcess.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.disposeInstances(InstanceProcess.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.disposeComponentConfigs(Resolver.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.disableComponents(Resolver.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.stoppingBundle(SCRManager.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.bundleChanged(SCRManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEventPrivileged(Framework.java:1569)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1505)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1500)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.decFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.shutdown(StartLevelManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.suspend(InternalSystemBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.shutdown(Framework.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.close(Framework.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core 4 0 2013-03-12 13:47:02.673
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.BlockedJobsDialog.createBlockedDialog(BlockedJobsDialog.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchDialogBlockedHandler.showBlocked(WorkbenchDialogBlockedHandler.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchDialogBlockedHandler.showBlocked(WorkbenchDialogBlockedHandler.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.EventLoopProgressMonitor.setBlocked(EventLoopProgressMonitor.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.reportBlocked(JobManager.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.join(JobManager.java:907)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.stop(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:870)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.core.ProvisioningAgent.unregisterService(ProvisioningAgent.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.core.ProvisioningAgent.removedService(ProvisioningAgent.java:183)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerRemoved(ServiceTracker.java:956)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerRemoved(ServiceTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.untrack(AbstractTracked.java:341)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:819)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.unregister(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.disposeInstances(InstanceProcess.java:356)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.disposeInstances(InstanceProcess.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.disposeComponentConfigs(Resolver.java:717)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.disableComponents(Resolver.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.stoppingBundle(SCRManager.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.bundleChanged(SCRManager.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEventPrivileged(Framework.java:1569)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1505)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.publishBundleEvent(Framework.java:1500)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:506)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.decFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.shutdown(StartLevelManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.suspend(InternalSystemBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.shutdown(Framework.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.close(Framework.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-03-12 13:47:04.270
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-03-12 13:47:04.273
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-03-12 13:47:04.274
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-03-12 13:47:04.276
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-03-12 13:47:04.277
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-03-12 13:47:04.279
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-03-12 13:47:04.280
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-03-12 13:47:04.282
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-03-12 13:47:04.283
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-03-12 13:47:04.284
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.repository.RepositoryRegistryUpdateJob
```

Comment: can you try reinstalling it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out. Go to yourWorkspace/.metadata/.plugins and delete everything in there.
Eclipse will start and repopulate the folder.

Comment: This worked for me but it cleared my whole workspace. i had to reimport my projects and configure perspective, settings, etc. I'm not sure if this was caused by deleting the folder mentioned or by the problem that made my eclipse complain in the first place

Comment: yeah same thing happened to me when i did it but that was the only solution i found :(
I guess you could try to find out which specific folder was messing with eclipse... i tried that but after i deleted half of them with no luck i just deleted the whole thing and it worked.

Comment: I removed all folders from "Workspace/.metadata/.plugins" apart from "org.eclipse.core.resources" plugin. Thanks to this Eclipse retained the projects.

Answer (score 301):

I used `eclipse -clean -clearPersistedState` and that worked for me. You will lose your window layout configuration, but that seems minor to me.

For Linux systems try: `./eclipse -clean -clearPersistedState`

See [Eclipse JUNO doesn't start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310970/eclipse-juno-doesnt-start?rq=1)

Comment: That did the trick for me. No need to wipe out all the plugins in .metadata/.plugins

Comment: Worked for me with Eclipse Juno, men you saved me a lot of work.

Comment: That did the trick! How come -clearPersistedState isn't in the eclipse documentation? http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fruntime-options.html&resultof=%22startup%22%20%22options%22%20%22option%22

Comment: Yea this works for me also everytime . But the reason here is this wil l only work if your eclipse cannot start because of " Job found still running after platform shutdown" in other cases like " out of heap memory" n etc this will not work

Comment: Worked also for me (luna.) Just right click in windows and add "-clean -clearPersistedState" behind target (Link tab).

Comment: Worked Perfectly!!! In my case (linux), I required: ./eclipse -clean -clearPersistedState

Comment: -clean did not work, but, using -clean -clearPersistedState did work, Thanks

Comment: _-clean_ could not work for me too, your solution worked. Thanks a lot. You've saved me a lot of time.

Comment: when eclipse fault to start there are always a lot of variables... running "./eclipse -clean -refresh -clearPersistedState"  worked for me

Comment: Brilliant! This works for Spring Tool Suite 3.8.1 on Neon. Many thanks.

Comment: Works with MyEclipse 2017, this just saved my day. I was stumbling upon solutions which never worked from morning. Thanks :)

Answer (score 47):

Removing workbench.xmi under workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/ worked for me. It did not remove the existing projects.

Comment: For Indigo the same file is located: workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench\workbench.xml

Comment: To add - if you are testing a plugin and get this problem then you need to remove the plugin equivalent, which on my machine was: Eclipse/runtime-EclipseApplication/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xml

Comment: Ha! Yay self I just googled this and found my own helpful comment!

Comment: It worked! But worked similar to -clean -clearPersistedState where I lost my layout. the projects themselves were still there.

Comment: This did not work for me, but when [I deleted the org.eclipse.e4.workbench folder itself as well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18731927/1682559) (which was empty..) it did work.

Answer (score 40):

This works like champ on mac os or windows.

Remove workbench.xmi  located at *workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi*. Then start your Eclipse or ADT.  This will not erase your workspace or repository.

**Remove workbench.xmi cmd:**

> rm
>   workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi.

Comment: Its work fine. But can you elaborate why this is happening and how it solves after removing it?

Comment: Changes during runtime, are written back to the model.This is due to during the development somehow the workspace is corrupted. E.g. Stopping the Eclipse while debugging, caching issue, stopping Eclipse before settings are saved, running out of memory,  user moves a part to a new container via drag and drop.

If the RCP application is closed, theses changes are recorded and saved independently in a workbench.xmi.
[Look into this docs step #4.Constructing the runtime application model](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4Modularity/article.html#contributecomponents_userchanges/)

Comment: On windows the path was C:\Users\myname\Adobe Flash Builder 4.7\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.ui.workbench

Comment: Worked! But lost the layout/view similar to -clean -clearPersistedState. The projects themselves were still there, Thank you!. unlike removing the complete .plugins.

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
$ rm YOUR_PROJECT_DIR/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap
```

Original source: [Job found still running after platform shutdown eclipse](http://www.metod.si/job-found-still-running-after-platform-shutdown-eclipse/)

Comment: this always helps me after some strange background errors of incorrectly closing

Comment: worked for me. the original problem occurred after force quitting eclipse.

Comment: and don't forget to refresh the projects

Comment: This seemed to get my Eclipse loading again -- in my case, it was `13.snap` rather than `.snap`, but either way, seems to have solved my eclipse freeze-on-startup.

Answer (score 5):

I deleted the workbench.xmi in the folder workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/.

I got this error because a build hung and then I tried to quit. However, I had unsaved changes. This prompted the following errors in logfile about unsaved changes and jobs that are not finished.

Comment: this solved my problem without needing to delete all .plugins folder and lose all configuration data

Answer (score 4):

Today, I had the same problem. My eclipse refused to start. When I double clicked on Eclipse icon I was able to see splashscreen for a second and then nothing happen.
Tried most of the solutions here: removed lock file, renamed workspace, tried to start Eclipse with different clean parameters. I even put a new copy of Eclispe and tried to start with a new workspace. Nothing!

My logs were showing bunch of errors from yesterday when my workstation was rebooted at 17:45.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2014-12-17 17:45:12.178
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

In the end this very simple change (look below) saved my Eclipse together with my workspace!

**SOLUTION:**

I edited `eclipse.ini` and added following line:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin\javaw.exe
```

Eclipse has started again with all my projects inside! I hope this can help.

Comment: Found a nice article showing where these types of logs are and what you can do at: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t99010.html

This article is particularly good for older versions of Eclipse.

Comment: @iaforek Thanks iaforek, I had tried all methods above and nothing until your method. :-) adding the items to my .ini file worked for me and kept my workspace settings in tact - sweet!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe worth mentioning that when I had this problem I followed bia.migueis's advice - move everything out of the plugins folder - and the workspace would open again, minus a lot of my configuration.  But then after that, I copied/overwrote all the original files back into the plugins folder and opened the workspace again: it still worked and the settings I'd had before seemed to be intact.

Answer (score 1):

I moved workbench.xmi located at workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi to a backup folder.  Then started eclipse and waited for all background processes to finish.  Then I closed eclipse and moved my backup copy of workbench.xmi back (overwriting the one created with the last launch).  Eclipse launched fine and I got all my settings back.

Answer (score 1):

If you deleted all data in .metadata directory. There is a quick way to import all your projects again. Try this:

File --> Import --> General: Select Existing projects into workspace --> Select root directory: Browse to old workspace folder (the SAME with the current workspace folder is OK) --> Finish.

Answer (score 1):

I tried several of the options posted in this article, but it worked for me using this option in eclipse.ini:

-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla

Answer (score 0):

I tried the option above of moving the plugins but it didn't work. My solution was to delete the entire .metadata folder. This meant that I lost my defaults and had to import my projects again.

Answer (score 0):

*Read my answer if recently you have been using a VPN connection.*

Today I had the same exact issue and learned how to fix it without removing any plugins.
So I thought maybe I would share my own experience.

**My issue definitely had something to do with Spring Framework**

I was using a VPN connection over my internet connection.
**Once I disconnected my VPN, everything instantly turned right.**

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a network/proxy thing. I connect via wifi and a corporate gateway. Deleted workspace, reinstalled GGTS - still hangs. Turn off the network - launches fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem but I solve it by adding environment variable (Run --> Run Configuration --> Environment variable ) as

```
variable : java_ipv6
value : -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```