# Eclipse Kepler auto exit on loading workbench with error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler

When i start eclipse, on splash loading window, eclise auto exit with error:

```
        !SESSION 2013-09-05 14:52:04.771 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.I20130605-2000
    java.version=1.7.0_25
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2013-09-05 14:52:09.260
    !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.core.helpers.ServiceHelper.getService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.updateRoamingProfile(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.updateSelfProfile(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.getProfileMap(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.internalGetProfile(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.getProfile(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:178)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler.AutomaticUpdateScheduler.earlyStartup(AutomaticUpdateScheduler.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.runEarlyStartup(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:87)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.run(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:66)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2013-09-05 14:52:09.264
    !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getLog(InternalPlatform.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.getLog(Plugin.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.log(WorkbenchPlugin.java:830)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.logError(StatusManager.java:285)
        at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:200)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager$2.done(ProgressManager.java:467)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobListeners$3.notify(JobListeners.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobListeners.doNotify(JobListeners.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobListeners.done(JobListeners.java:152)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.endJob(JobManager.java:647)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.WorkerPool.endJob(WorkerPool.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:70)

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2013-09-05 14:52:09.267
    !MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Workbench early startup".
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.InternalPlatform.getLog(InternalPlatform.java:354)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Plugin.getLog(Plugin.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.log(WorkbenchPlugin.java:818)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EarlyStartupRunnable.handleException(EarlyStartupRunnable.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.handleException(SafeRunner.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:44)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$55.run(Workbench.java:2552)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I've tried:

- deleting workspace/.metadata/.lock
- delete the file WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap

But didn't solve this problem.

Comment: refer to this : http://superuser.com/questions/148179/eclipse-shows-splash-screen-and-closes-how-to-fix

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Solved when I delete `".\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench"` folder.
Follow [this](https://superuser.com/questions/148179/eclipse-shows-splash-screen-and-closes-how-to-fix).

Comment: Thank you @Sonroby, just to make it clear the folder is <ECLIPSE_WORKSPACE_PATH>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench

Comment: This worked for me but it deleted all my workspace preferences.

Comment: thank you so much! been grinding my teeth on this for an hour now :D

Comment: Good heavens, I'd never have figured that out. Thank you!

Comment: This solution fixed it immediately for me, but why does this happen? Everything worked for me for months, then out of the blue this issue came up, anyone know what causes this?

Comment: [Based on this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18282716/1682559) I deleted the `workbench.xmi` inside of the folder, but this didn't work. When I removed the (at that point empty) folder itself as well as you suggested, it did work. So thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try to start with an empty workspace or a fresh Eclipse installation. If they work, you can reimport the contents of your workspace and transfer the installed plugins (File > Export... > Installed Software Items, then Import).

Answer (score 1):

Just do this

```
rm -fr /worksapce/.metadata/.plugins/or.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
```

and then restart eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to your Java Workspace Folder --> .metadata --> .plugins --> org.eclipse.e4.workbench.... delete this folder.. it works for me, hopefully it will also work for you.

Comment: Hi @Rachit-Jain. Thanks for taking the effort to answer this. However, the accepted answer for this question is basically saying the same as you (at least as far as I see).

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Goto cd /opt/eclipse/
- Step 2: then vim eclipse.ini
- Step 3: Add this line at the end of the file
  "**-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false**"
- Step 4: ./eclipse

Try the above 4 steps. Issue will be resolved for eclipse in linux environment