# Exit code=127 when I start Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've installed Ubuntu 10.10, Eclipse Juno and Java 1.7.

Firstly, when I tried to start Eclipse, this last one said me that it doesn't exist a java runtime environment on my computer. So, I've created in the Eclipse directory deux others directory(jre/bin) within I put all the files from the bin directory of java.

After, When I started, I had this following errors :

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=127
/home/dark0502/Desktop/eclipse/jre/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/dark0502/Desktop/eclipse//plugin/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86
-showsplash /home/dark0502/Desktop/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/splash.bmp
-launcher /home/dark0502/Desktop/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/dark0502/Desktop/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807/eclipse_1502.so
-startup /home/dark0502/Desktop/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-exitdata 248015
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
-vm /home/dark0502/Desktop/eclipse/jre/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-jar /home/dark0502/Desktop/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar `
```

Do you have a solution ?

Thank you

Comment: You have to run: eclipse -clean -clearPersistedState 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372023/eclipse-will-not-start-and-i-havent-changed-anything

Answer (score 2):

Searching the net, it seems it was already reported:

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/eclipse-juno-start-up-error-127-a-4175418488/

And the solution suggested was:

> I figured it out. I installed JDK7 and was under the impression that
>   it would also install JRE with it. Whenever I went to anything that
>   used Java it said it was using 7 so I assumed it must have. I guess
>   the difference between the JDK and the JRE installed caused it to not
>   work

Comment: If this answer helped you overcome the problem, you can thank the author by marking it as the correct answer for your question. Just hover and click the "v"-shaped image in front of the number of votes