# Eclipse Ubuntu Install Error

Tags: java, eclipse

I've just installed the JDK, and now I'm installing Eclipse, and a error message comes up :

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=127
/usr/local/bin/java
-Xms256M
-Xmx1024M
-jar /home/adrien/Eclipseinst//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/adrien/Eclipseinst/eclipse-inst
-name Eclipse Installer
--launcher.library /home/adrien/Eclipseinst//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417/eclipse_1612.so
-startup /home/adrien/Eclipseinst//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 50001a
-data @none
-vm /usr/local/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms256M
-Xmx1024M
-jar /home/adrien/Eclipseinst//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.100.v20150511-1540.jar
```

I don't know what's causing that.

Comment: Maybe you better ask here: [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455305/exit-code-127-when-i-start-eclipse) question.

Comment: Your last line is a duplicate of the third parameter. Remove it.

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? Obtained from where? Which version of Java? Obtained from where? What hav you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If Java is in your path Eclipse should work directly after unzipping the distribution you downloaded. Try again and do not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudu apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade.
sudo apt-get install jre
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

add java run time enviroments