# Eclipse Hello World Plugin Error. Compiles ok, Gives error on Run

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am following this (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html) tutorial to create a hello world plugin for eclipse. But I am unable to run this plugin.
I am getting these errors: http://pastebin.com/jAuqwH7t

Comment: I have tried that example on my eclipse kepler, that works without any exceptions. Which eclipse do you have and os version?

Comment: OS: Windows 7 64 bit, Eclipse: Juno service release 2

Comment: maybe [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16901800/2894369) can help you.