# AdMob issue with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I am trying to get AdMob to work on my app with Eclipse. For that I already implemented following steps:

1. Signed up on AdMob and created an ad
2. Inserted following to Manifest.xml:

   ```
   <!-- This meta-data tag is required to use Google Play Services. -->
   <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

   <activity
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
       android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
   ```
3. Installed and imported `google-play-services_lib` (checked copy files into workspace)
4. Added `google-play-services_lib` as library to project
5. In my layout xml I have this:

   ```
   <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ads:adSize="BANNER"
       ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-2756687115022088/XXXXXXXXXX" >
   </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
   ```

Also I included `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`

6.Added following to my Activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.example.adexample.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }
}
```

**7.Now when I try to run the app on my device I always get following
    error:**

```
unable to execute dex gc overhead limit exceeded
```

**What I tried, but no success:** increase memory size in eclipse.ini and sometimes Eclipse doesn't start and I have to do following step: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18282716/3829021

Comment: Are you sure that this error comes from the admob integration?

Comment: I think due to google-play-service_lib... When I try to launch projects without google play service lib then there are no problems. I have no clue why google play services causes this gc overhead.

Comment: Are you testing it on emulator? Also you should enable test-ads for emulator by adding `.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)` to your AdRequest.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this issue just by re-installing Eclipse and Android SDK and imported google play service lib into project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this just now trying to integrate admob. This is a generic eclipse memory issue and not specific to AdMob integration.

Here's the fix that worked for me:

1. Edited eclipse.ini in the eclipse installation folder (In my case:
   C:\Program Files\eclipse\eclipse.ini)
2. Increased the memory values in
   the lines starting with Xms*

   from

   ```
   -Xms40m 
   -Xmx512m
   ```

   to

   ```
   -Xms512m
   -Xmx1024m
   ```

Credit: [Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471194/unable-to-execute-dex-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded-in-eclipse)