# Eclipse exits automatically exit code 127

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, eclipse-luna

Eclipse exits automatically and suddenly and I think that reason might be due to a plugin. **The exit happens right when I want for the auto complete feature or eclipse tries for it.**

The message it gives when exiting is:

> JVM terminated. Exit code=127
>   /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java
>   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
>   -Xms40m
>   -Xmx512m
>   -jar /home/stormdev/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
>   -os linux
>   -ws gtk
>   -arch x86_64
>   -showsplash /home/stormdev/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.2.v20150204-1700/splash.bmp
>   -launcher /home/stormdev/Downloads/eclipse/eclipse
>   -name Eclipse
>   --launcher.library /home/stormdev/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20150204-1316/eclipse_1607.so
>   -startup /home/stormdev/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
>   --launcher.appendVmargs
>   -exitdata f800f
>   -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
>   -vm /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java
>   -vmargs
>   -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
>   -Xms40m
>   -Xmx512m
>   -jar /home/stormdev/Downloads/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar

What can be the reason for this?

I am using Eclipse luna on centOS. using oracle java7.

When i try to run eclipse on command line it gives me this error

> /opt/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libwebkit-1.0.so.2: undefined symbol: soup_message_set_first_party

Tried steps:

- eclipse -clean -clearPersistedState didn't help me
- switching workspace hasn't been helpful either

**Update**

yum update libsoup command has resolved my issue.

*Downvoters, please check the questioner problem before discarding it as trivial*

Comment: Do you people think that I do not search google before asking this question? Before you downvote you need to check what the problem is.

Comment: try to run from command line eclipse -clean

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372023/eclipse-will-not-start-and-i-havent-changed-anything

Comment: @SaritAdhikari this is the message in command line. symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libwebkit-1.0.so.2: undefined symbol: soup_message_set_first_party

Comment: @mstfdz Same thing. If i get the solution there why would I ask here?

Comment: can you try it in new workspace? If it displays no error , import projects from existing workspace to new one.

Comment: Which eclipse version you are using

Comment: @CoderNeji Eclipse luna on centOs

Comment: i don't know about what centos is... see this link... may be its helpful for you... https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=174642

Comment: @SaritAdhikari Switching workspace didn't help me.

Comment: The downvotes are not because your problem is trivial.  They are because you left out most of the **relevant** details in the original version of the question.  That makes it a bad question ... and worthy of downvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this error message:

```
symbol lookup error: /usr/lib64/libwebkit-1.0.so.2: undefined symbol: soup_message_set_first_party
```

What it seems to be saying is that the `libwebkit` shared library can't be loaded because there is an incompatibility with the library that provides the `soup_message_set_first_party`.  Based on [this link](https://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/stable/SoupMessage.html), I'd say the incompatible library is `libsoup`.

So, it seems as if you have somehow managed to get incompatible versions of libwebkit and libsoup on your system.  The copy of libwebkit clearly comes from /usr/lib64, but it would be interesting (and possibly informative) to know where libsoup comes from and what version it is.

On my Fedora 20 system, which works with Eclipse, I have these libraries / symlinks, provided by the package management system.  I assume they are compatible, because I don't see the errors that you do when I run Eclipse.

```
/usr/lib64/libsoup-gnome-2.4.so.1.7.0
/usr/lib64/libsoup-gnome-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib64/libsoup-2.4.so.1.7.0
/usr/lib64/libsoup-2.4.so.1
/usr/lib64/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0
/usr/lib64/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0
/usr/lib64/libwebkitgtk-1.0.so.0.19.16
/usr/lib64/libwebkitgtk-3.0.so.0.19.16
```

**UPDATE** - After further digging, I don't think my theory above is correct.  I can see no obvious dependency between libwebkit and libsoup.  (The puzzling thing is that on my system I have libwebkitgtk and not libwebkit.  But that might just be because my system is not a clean Fedora / Gnome install.  Rather it has had KDE added "after the fast".)

If that theory is incorrect, then the next thing is to see if this is a plugin problem.  Backup your existing Eclipse install AND your workspaces, and then install a fresh copy of Luna without any plugins.  If that works, then install your plugins one at a time, doing a Eclipse exit + relaunch + test between each one.  When you manage to reproduce the problem you have most likely identified the offending plugin.  (If you can't reproduce the problem, you have "solved" the problem.)

Comment: on my system 
ls libsoup*
libsoup-2.4.so.1      libsoup-gnome-2.4.so.1
libsoup-2.4.so.1.3.0  libsoup-gnome-2.4.so.1.3.0

Comment: I have installed a fresh copy of eclipse and the error still repeats.

Comment: Are you saying that the problem occurs with a fresh copy of Eclipse with no plugins?

Comment: Yes. I have tried with fresh copy of eclipse. i have used yum update ilbsoup and it worked for me.