# JVM terminated. Exit code=127

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, java-17

I updated CentOS 7 with jdk-17.0.5 and for java 17 support I also downloaded latest sts-4.19.1. When I open STS, it shows the error in the  screenshot below.

[image]

The latest version of STS should run on CentOS 7 with Java 17.

Comment: Try to run eclipse from the command line, and see if you get additional info . Also this seems related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594269/eclipse-exits-automatically-exit-code-127

Comment: @Arnaud not working this solution for me. Its eclipse close automatically issue. In my case i am starting fresh sts

Comment: The Java VM crashed. Why you run STS with Java installed on your system (`/opt/jdk-17.0.5/bin/java`) instead of the Java included in STS? How did you install STS (there are different ways)? What does `/opt/jdk-17.0.5/bin/java -version` print? Which GTK version do you have?

Comment: Don't use images for text information.