# Eclipse will not start after any changes

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using eclipse kepler to developer some java program and this morning I have a new problem: eclipse doesn't start. Until yesterday everything worked, but this morning when I try to execute it i get

[image]

The log file contains the foolowing exceptions:

```
    !SESSION 2015-07-09 09:55:31.429 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.7.0_60
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-07-09 09:55:31.757
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.launch(Framework.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start() of bundle org.eclipse.osgi.
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.resume(InternalSystemBundle.java:225)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: SHA1 digest error for org/eclipse/osgi/internal/module/ResolverImpl.class
    at sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier.verify(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarVerifier$VerifierStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.StateManager.createResolver(StateManager.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.StateManager.initializeSystemState(StateManager.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.StateManager.createSystemState(StateManager.java:195)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.readStateData(BaseStorage.java:843)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.getStateManager(BaseStorage.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.getState(BaseAdaptor.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.frameworkStart(BaseStorage.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.frameworkStart(BaseAdaptor.java:250)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.SystemBundleActivator.start(SystemBundleActivator.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
    ... 12 more
```

I trid to follow some SO thread like

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372023/eclipse-will-not-start-and-i-havent-changed-anything)

bu nothing to do, How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Does this happen before or after you select your workspace? (If you have a default workspace you might not get this option).

Comment: @Magnilex This happen before the workspace choose.

Comment: Have you tried running `eclipse -clean -refresh` yet? If that doesn't help, start with a different workspace (run `eclipse -data <your_workspace_location>`) to see if it's a problem with your installation or the workspace. If it's the installation, try reinstalling (might be worth trying anyway now that kepler is behind two releases).

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using?  Have you recently changed your JDK or JRE?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  No i didn't change any java version, I'm using jdk1.7.0_60

Comment: @Axel I tried but nothing seems work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something looks wrong in Eclipse own jars,
The error indicates a failure wile loading classes from one jar,
Try to get a fresh copy of the jars and replace it inside Eclipse directory.

If that didn't work, your best bet would be to install a fresh copy of eclipse (and I suggest you install Eclipse-Luna)

Comment: You could try reinstalling Eclipse and see if that fixes the problem.  This might be the fastest route to getting back to development.

Comment: _and I suggest you install Eclipse-Luna_. Why not Eclipse Mars, the latest release?

Comment: I have no experience with Mars, it might be better but I suggested based on my experience, Thanks for your note.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing it by using eclipse-inst-win64.exe. That fixed the problem for me:

[image]