# Error in eclipse juno upon opening

Tags: java, eclipse, mylyn

After having Eclipse installed and working fine for over a year, I opened up Eclipse Juno today and got a error message on opening the workspace. I am using Windows 8 64-bit, Java 64-bit, and Eclipse 64-bit.  I have since tried re-installing Java and Eclipse without any effect. If anyone can help me get Eclipse working it would be much appreciated. The error log is as follows:

```
!SESSION 2013-06-08 16:46:09.718 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_21
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2013-06-08 16:46:11.617
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-06-08 16:46:14.621
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1232)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1225)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.builds.ui.BuildsStartup$1.runInUIThread(BuildsStartup.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3814)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 0 2013-06-08 16:46:14.624
!MESSAGE An unexpected exception was thrown.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1232)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1225)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.updateActiveShell(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:924)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider.getCurrentState(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.services.WorkbenchSourceProvider$6.handleEvent(WorkbenchSourceProvider.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1262)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1052)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.WM_ACTIVATE(Decorations.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_ACTIVATE(Shell.java:2145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4525)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1627)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2069)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4976)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.BringWindowToTop(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.bringToTop(Decorations.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.open(Shell.java:1217)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:797)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.InternalDialog.open(InternalDialog.java:327)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.doAddStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManagerImpl.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.addStatusAdapter(WorkbenchStatusDialogManager.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.showStatusAdapter(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.WorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandler.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.handle(IDEWorkbenchErrorHandler.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.handle(WorkbenchErrorHandlerProxy.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.ui.statushandlers.StatusManager.handle(StatusManager.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager$2.done(ProgressManager.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobListeners$3.notify(JobListeners.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobListeners.doNotify(JobListeners.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobListeners.done(JobListeners.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.JobManager.endJob(JobManager.java:647)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.InternalJob.done(InternalJob.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.jobs.Job.done(Job.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3814)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2013-06-08 16:46:14.632
!MESSAGE An internal error has occurred.
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1232)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1225)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.builds.ui.BuildsStartup$1.runInUIThread(BuildsStartup.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.UIJob$1.run(UIJob.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3814)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-06-08 16:46:14.996
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4361)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4276)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4144)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3814)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1232)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow(Workbench.java:1225)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.monitor.ui.ActivityContextManager$3.run(ActivityContextManager.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    ... 18 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.ui 4 0 2013-06-08 16:46:15.867
!MESSAGE Monitor UI stop failed
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.monitor.ui.ActivityContextManager.stop(ActivityContextManager.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.monitor.ui.MonitorUiPlugin.stop(MonitorUiPlugin.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.stopWorker(BundleHost.java:510)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.suspend(AbstractBundle.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.suspendBundle(Framework.java:1206)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.decFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:592)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.shutdown(StartLevelManager.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.InternalSystemBundle.suspend(InternalSystemBundle.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.shutdown(Framework.java:692)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.close(Framework.java:600)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.shutdown(EclipseStarter.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-06-08 16:46:16.612
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-06-08 16:46:16.613
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-06-08 16:46:16.614
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-06-08 16:46:16.614
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-06-08 16:46:16.615
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-06-08 16:46:16.615
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplaceDropAdapter$1

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-06-08 16:46:16.616
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-06-08 16:46:16.616
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.mylyn.internal.tasks.ui.TasksUiPlugin$TasksUiInitializationJob

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-06-08 16:46:16.617
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-06-08 16:46:16.617
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-06-08 16:46:16.618
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-06-08 16:46:16.618
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.ExtensionEventDispatcherJob

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 2 2 2013-06-08 16:46:16.619
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.ui.internal.AbstractWorkingSetManager$9
```

Comment: Have you tried starting it with a different (new) workspace?

Comment: Just did, and unfortunately for me it worked

Comment: The message you provide seems to say exactly what you must do.

Comment: You can find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310970/eclipse-juno-doesnt-start/12045547#12045547)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  *Kninnug*  I have figured out that the issue is in my workspace not eclipse itself.  I ended up just importing everything in to the new workspace.  thank you everyone for your help though.

Answer (score 3):

I think your answer is [here](http://tweakux.wikkii.com/wiki/Eclipse):

```
$ mv <workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap ~/temp/
```

or

```
$ rm <workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap
```

Comment: In my case delete content of org.eclipse.core.resources solved issue

Answer (score 1):

Start Eclipse with Clean parameter.

```
eclipse.exe -clean
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem with Eclipse Juno, which I use for Android development.

As a workaround for Windows, I launch it from the console like this:

C:\path\to\eclipse\eclipse -clean

or

DELETE: /[PATH TO WORKSPACE]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources

if none of the above works, have a read at this  http://www.metod.si/job-found-still-running-after-platform-shutdown-eclipse/

Answer (score 0):

problem is with workspace/project you are working on and not with eclipse. One solution would be if you are using maven is to clean and install.