# Eclipse stucks on Loading org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui, how to fix it?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

today I restarted Eclipse 4.4 and I saw that it got stuck at Loading org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui:

[image]

I tried to follow this thread on SO -> [Eclipse hangs on loading workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972034/eclipse-hangs-on-loading-workbench), deleting the .lock, *.snap files inside the .metadata directory, but neither of the two has worked for me, I guess the problem is not concerned the issue the OP in the linked thread had, cause he had a problem with loading com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.

Anyway, is there a possible solution I can apply?

EDIT: this is the output of the eclipse -clean -refresh start (I use STS)

```
machine:~ user$ ./STS -clean -refresh
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: The org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the state location was initialized.  Will retry after the state location is initialized.
Starting Groovy-Eclipse compiler resolver.  Specified compiler level: unspecified
113 2.3.7.xx-201411241807-e44 = STARTING
114 2.2.2.xx-201411241807-e44 = STARTING
115 2.1.8.xx-201411241807-e44 = STARTING
116 2.0.7.xx-201411241807-e44 = STARTING
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /Users/antony/STS/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.5.0.20140606-0033.xml
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
```

Comment: Did U tried with empty .metadata ??? (backup it etc.)

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003747/error-in-eclipse-juno-upon-opening

Comment: Thank you for the .metadata hint and for the link, I have tried to `mv .metadata .metadata.backup` and Eclipse started, so the problem is definitely related to the .metadata folder, but now all my settings and preferences are not user, how can I recover them?

Comment: if U got backuped .metadata. U could check in trash.

Comment: I have a .metadata.backup in the workspace folder, I have tried to rename it back to .metadata only but it's not working, what should I do?

Comment: you could delete part of metadata only releated to your latest work.
Or even less. It is up to U if it is worth effort.

Comment: I end up resetting all my preferences again! Anyway, thanks for your interest and help!