# Eclipse won't reopen workspace after crash

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

Eclipse crashed while working on a project, now when I want to reopen the project I get the following message.

> An error has occurred. See the log file /FOLDERS/.metadata/.log

I can open other workspaces without any problem. I remember having this problem some time ago and it was just a lock or something that Eclipse should have removed when shutting down properly which now it didn't. So what I used to do was to start eclipse, cancel on the workspace launcher and restart eclipse. This doesn't seem to work any more. Is there another way to open the workspace again?

For those interested, the log contains the following.

```
!SESSION 2014-07-30 15:20:58.106 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.3.2.M20140221-1700
java.version=1.7.0_55
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-07-30 15:21:02.696
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.preferences 4 2 2014-07-30 15:21:03.962
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.equinox.preferences".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.PreferenceConstants.initializeDefaultValues(PreferenceConstants.java:3739)
...

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-07-30 15:21:03.975
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui (360).
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.jdt.ui.
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:734)
...

Root exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceConverter
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin.ensurePreferenceStoreBackwardsCompatibility(JavaPlugin.java:448)
...

!ENTRY org.apache.log4j 2 0 2014-07-30 15:21:03.981
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared.internal.Activator  - Disabling JDT use. : org/eclipse/jdt/ui/JavaUI


!ENTRY org.apache.log4j 2 0 2014-07-30 15:21:04.486
!MESSAGE org.eclipse.xtext.ui.shared.internal.Activator  - Disabling JDT use. : org/eclipse/jdt/ui/JavaUI


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2014-07-30 15:21:07.129
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceConverter
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.themes.ThemeElementHelper.installFont(ThemeElementHelper.java:104)
...
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse JUNO doesn't start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310970/eclipse-juno-doesnt-start)

Answer (score 1):

For me, deleting the **.snap file** from location **.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/** worked and was able to start eclipse after that.

Above solution is mentioned [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=372621)